# Reverse geocode returns random Asia location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I am changing longtime into latitude and for some reason when this code has a longitude and latitude from somewhere in the usa, (stockholm sweden works) it gives me a random location in asia. Any ideas?

```
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude), completionHandler: { (placemarks:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            var placemark = placemarks.last as? CLPlacemark
            var locationString = ""
            if let administrative = placemark?.administrativeArea{
                locationString = locationString + administrative
                if let subadminstrative = placemark?.subAdministrativeArea{
                    locationString = locationString + subadminstrative
                }
```

Comment: What does "changing longtime into latitude" mean exactly?  What are the exact coordinates you are giving to the geocoder?  Remember that the longitudes for the US are negative (meaning "West") and positive values mean "East".  So for example latitude 42 and longitude -100 is in Nebraska, US but latitude 42 and longitude +100 is in China.

Comment: Whoa obviously didn't proofread. I meant changing coordinates into a string of the location. I will check the coords